# How to make a forest plot for a mixed model

Tags: r, r-forestplot

How to make a forest plots for mixed models co-effiecents and their corresponding confidence interval.
I tried this code

```
Model = lme (fixed = score~ Age+Sex+yearsofeducation+walkspeed,
random = ~1|ID, 
data=DB,
na.action = na.omit, method = "ML", 
)
plot_summs (model)
```

However, I want the OR in the forest plots to be ordered in a descending fashion.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten hey, what do you mean by reproducible data? I am pretty new to R or Stack overflow. 
Thanks.

Comment: I just want to make a Forest plot to present the mixed model regression coefficients in a neat way.

Comment: Hi @Sari Katish, You can share your data using `dput(DB)` in your console and copy and paste that in your question above, so that we can help you better.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want, but such plots are often referred to as *caterpillar plots*: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+caterpillar+plot . Do you want to see just the random-effects coefficients (BLUPs) ?

Comment: @BenBolker, I want to plot the fixed effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m just adding one more option to Ben Bolker’s excellent answer: [using the `modelsummary` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary) (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

With that package, you can use the `modelplot()` function to create a forest plot, and the `coef_map` argument to rename and reorder coefficients. If you are estimating a logit model and want the odds ratios, you can use the `exponentiate` argument.

The order in which you insert coefficients in the `coef_map` vector sorts them in the plot, from bottom to top. For example:

```r
library(lme4)
library(modelsummary)

mod <- lmer(mpg ~ wt + drat + (1 | gear), data = mtcars)

modelplot(
    mod,
    coef_map = c("(Intercept)" = "Constant",
                 "drat" = "Rear Axle Ratio",
                 "wt" = "Weight"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a "coefficient plot", not a "forest plot". (A forest plot is used in meta-analyses, when you are comparing the magnitude of estimates of the *same* effect from many different studies.)

### example setup

This is a slightly silly example, but should be close enough to yours (not clear to me why you're mentioning OR (= odds ratios?), these are typically from a logistic regression ... ?)

```r
library(nlme)
mtcars <- transform(mtcars, cylgear = interaction(cyl, gear))
m1 <- lme(mpg ~ disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec,
    random = ~1|cylgear,
    data = mtcars)
```

### coefficient plots: dotwhisker

You could get *approximately* what you want directly from the `dotwhisker` package, but it won't sort effects (or not easily, as far as I know):

```r
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom.mixed)  ## required to 'tidy' (process) lme fits
dwplot(m1, effects = "fixed")
```

### coefficient plots: tidyverse

I usually do the processing myself, as I prefer increased flexibility.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tt <- (m1
    ## extract estimates and CIs
    |> tidy(effects = "fixed", conf.int = TRUE)
    ## usually *don't* want to compare intercept (dwplot does this automatically)
    |> filter(term != "(Intercept)")
    ## scale parameters by 2SD - usually necessary for comparison
    |> dotwhisker::by_2sd(data = mtcars)
    ## take only the bits we need, rename some (cosmetic)
    |> select(term, estimate, lwr = conf.low, upr = conf.high)
    ## order terms by estimate value
    |> mutate(across(term, ~reorder(factor(.), estimate)))
)

gg0 <- (ggplot(tt,
               aes(estimate, term))
    + geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = lwr, xmax = upr))
    + geom_vline(xintercept = 0, lty = 2)
)
print(gg0)
```

[image]

The only remaining/possibility tricky question here is what to do if you have positive and negative coefficients of similar magnitude. If you want to sort by *absolute value* then

```r
|> mutate(across(term, ~reorder(factor(.), estimate, 
 FUN = function(x) mean(abs(x)))
```

although this gets a bit ugly.

If you like the tidyverse you can substitute `forcats::fct_reorder` for `reorder`.